# Unable to invoke CFC Remotely (Flex 4 / ColdFusion 9)

Tags: apache-flex, coldfusion, flex4, coldfusion-9, cfc

We recently updated to ColdFusion 9 (from 8) and Flex 4 (from 3).

Now receiving below error when attempting to load Flex portion:

```
roSessionVO.init()
Unable to invoke CFC - The method 'init' in component
C:\ColdFusion9\wwwroot\web_apps\site\model\SessionVO.cfc cannot be accessed remotely.
```

Do we need to re-export the Flex project to fix problem or maybe code from /flex/remoting-config.xml needs to be updated?

Please don't hesitate to request more info - not too sure where to start?!

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some examples of your Flex and ColdFusion code would help, but that error indicates that the "init" method is not marked as access="remote".  There was a bug early on in ColdFusion 8 that treated methods with access="public" as though they were set to "remote", so your Flex app was probably able to work anyway.  This was a security issue.  Only methods explicitly exposed as remote should be available.

To fix, most likely you would change your cffunction tag to be access="remote".

```
<cffunction name="init" access="remote" ...>
```